# WSO2 IS error when creating user store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I try to create an LDAP Base user store in WSO2 IS 5.3.0 I always get the following error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-04-03 11:40:49,521] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.UserStoreConfigAdminService} -   Error occurred during the transformation process of C:\WSO2IS~1.0\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\userstores\myUserStore.xml
org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.utils.IdentityUserStoreMgtException:  Error occurred during the transformation process of C:\WSO2IS~1.0\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\userstores\myUserSotre.xml
```

I have tried previous version and it fails till 5.0.0, in which I succeed in create the user store. User store config in WSO2 ESB seems to works the same way that WSO2 IS user store, so, I configured the user store in WSO2 ESB, and copy the myUserSotre.xml generated by WSO2 ESB just in the same path where IS failed to find the file.

That worked, and result in WSO2 IS recognizing the User Store. I can see the users from the user store in WSO2 IS user store. However, if I try update the "forced" user store, it keeps throwing the error.

I am using windows 7 and jdk 8.

This is the xml from ESB and IS 5.0.0 that works if I paste it in IS 5.3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
      <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=Manager,dc=company,dc=com</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://IP:HOST</Property>
      <Property name="ConnectionPassword">password</Property>
      <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=People,dc=company,dc=com</Property>
      <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
      <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
      <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
      <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
      <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
      <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
      <Property name="ReadGroups">false</Property>
      <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=system</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
      <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
      <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
      <Property name="MemberOfAttribute"/>
      <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
      <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
      <Property name="DomainName">ldap</Property>
      <Property name="Description"/>
</UserStoreManager>
```

Is there any issue about this? Is there extra configuration needed?

Comment: can you share your user store xml?

Comment: We do not have that XML. The error is launched when generating it, so it fails to generate it. I add the xml from ESB/IS 5.0.0

Comment: Are you running on Windows10? The same error is reported in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5801

Comment: I use Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in Windows because of the file path encoding. Currently this is not fixed from WSO2 side. As a work around, you can rename WSO2IS~1.0 folder not contain the '~' character. eg. rename it with WSO2IS and try.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. Set environment variable CARBON_HOME to the path of your wso2 IS folder.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10, thanks! Path to wso2is folder didn't contain any long names so the accepted answer wasn't an issue.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you, and thanks for comment. :)